# Lipschitz continuity implies integral of f(x) - integral f(c) is less than or equal to K(b-a)^2

Tags: real-analysis

I am attempting to prove that a function f satisfying Lipschitz continuity on modulus K ($|f'(x)|\leq K$) implies that $|\int_a^bf(x)dx-\int_a^bf(c)|\leq K(b-a)^2$ for all $c\in [a, b]$.

I have tried working backwards from $|f'(x)|\leq K$ to get that the integral of $f$ must be less than or equal to $K(b-a)^2$ but that hasn't helped me as I still can't handle $-\int_a^bf(c)$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does $c$ denote?

Comment: ah I forgot to add $c\in [a, b]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $x, c \in [a,b]$ you have
$$|f(x)-f(c)| \le K |x-c| \le K(b-a)$$
Hence
$$\left| \int_a^b (f(x)-f(c)) dx\right| \le \int_a^b |f(x)-f(c)| dx \le \int_a^b K(b-a) dx = K(b-a)^2$$